# bash failing the second part of command

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I am using below command

```
envconsul env | awk '{print "export " $0}' > ~/.profile
```

if the envconsul fails(i.e- the first part of the command before pipe) - then the .profile file is getting blank. I don't want that. All I want is to just fail the command without executing after the pipe (|) part.

Is this possible in POSIX shell one-liner or I need to write a bash script?

so far I tried with appending set -o pipefail , adding && but none of them are working. Any suugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, write to temporary file and exit if the command fails. If it succeeds, move the temporary file into place.

Here's my take on it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# exit on error
set -e
set -o pipefail

cleanup() {
    # make sure the temporary file is removed
    rm -f "$tmp"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

# create a temporary file in the home directory
tmp="$(mktemp -p ~)"
target="${HOME}/.profile"

# run your command and redirect the output to the temporary file
envconsul env | awk '{print "export " $0}' > "$tmp"

# set the same permissions as the current file has
chmod --reference="$target" "$tmp"

# move the temporary file into place
mv -f "$tmp" "$target"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need both a temporary file and pipefail:

```
 set -o pipefail
 if envconsul env | awk '{print "export " $0}' > ~/.profile.tmp
 then
   mv ~/.profile.tmp ~/.profile
   echo "Success"all stages but the last are ignored, making it harder to check whether the commands succeeded.
 fi
```

Without a temp file, `~/.profile` is truncated before the pipeline finishes, so success and failure don't matter.

Without `pipefail`, the exit status of `envconsul env` is ignored, since normally only the last stage is considered.

If you want it POSIX compliant, you can write the result of `envconsul env` to a file first, and check its status independently.

Comment: exit code of failed envconsul env command is 14 which is non-zero.

Comment: @Jadu Yes? So if it fails, `.profile` will not get overwritten. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Yes - I want that. I will try this script and let you know. It seems all other suggestions are not working - so only way to fix this is to use a script like above.

Comment: This script and my comment essentially does the same thing (given that `set -o pipefile` is set). I don't understand how it can't be working.

Answer (score 0):

Two-liner:

```
output="$(envconsul env 2>/dev/null | awk '{print "export " $0}' )"
test -n "${output}" && echo "${output}" > ~/.profile
```

EDIT (after comment):
When you do need to check the result of `envconsul` directly (not with the length), you can do something like

```
output="$(envconsul env 2>/dev/null)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "${output}" | awk '{print "export " $0}' ) > ~/.profile
else
   echo "Some other action"
fi
```

Comment: It's kind of nice but if `envconsul` fails after having printed something, the result will be a "half" `.profile`. Also, if `envconsul` succeeds without any output, `.profile` will not be cleared. There's also a slim risk that writing directly to `.profile` may corrupt it (disk full etc). 

`output="$(set -o pipefail; envconsul env 2>/dev/null | awk '{print "export " $0}' )" && echo "${output}" > ~/.profile` would make it almost as safe as moving a temporary into place.

Comment: In your attempt, try removing `set -e`.

Comment: :-) Now it's ok. Prefer `[[` tests in [tag:bash] though - or you can do as @thatotherguy: `if output="$(envconsul env 2>/dev/null)"; then`.

If I remove `set -e` I'll need to check the return value everywhere. I don't want to risk missing a single error and all errors should lead to that the script aborts, so `set -e` is saving me a lot of problems. I don't see why I should remove it?

Comment: You can edit the way you like. Some people love the `set -e` option, others hate it. In different shells (flavours/versions) scripts might work different, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105. I stopped using `set -e`, you can also use `set +e; some code; set -e` when you don't want to break existing code.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a matter of taste. I use `set -e` when all errors should lead to termination. Otherwise, I usually check the exit status.

Answer (score 0):

It may be tempting to use pipes for this application, but it complicates error handling.

When it is not large amounts of data, it is easier to store the output of the command in a string and do standard error checking:

```
environment=$(./envconsul env) && awk '{print "export " $0}' <<<"${environment}" >~/.profile
```